# How do I Unit Test NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()?

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, nservicebus

I'm building a WCF service that receives requests on an external IP and translates them into messages that are sent via NServiceBus.

One of my unit tests invokes `Global.Application_Start()`, which performs the configuration of the application, and then attempts to resolve the web service to
validate that the container can build up all of the dependencies.

This works fine when I'm using `Configure.With()` in my windows services, but
the call to `Configure.WithWeb()` fails in this context (presumably because the "bin"
directory does not exist?).

Is it possible to unit test a method that calls `Configure.WithWeb()`, or should I
just use the overload for `Configure.With()` that takes a directory name?

Comment: Depends how complicated you want to get, but you could wrap a generic BootStrapper interface/class around the call and swap it out based on the current context.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue.  The exception that I'm getting is this: ArgumentNullException
at System.IO.DirectoryInfo..ctor(String path)
at NServiceBus.Configure.GetAssembliesInDirectoryWithExtension(String path, String extension, String[] assembliesToSkip) in Configure.cs: line 226
at NServiceBus.Configure.<GetAssembliesInDirectory>d__7.MoveNext() in Configure.cs: line 217

Answer (score 0):

I created a new startup class like so:

```
public class NonWebRunAtStartup : IRunAtStartup
{
    public void InitializeInfrastructure(object container)
    {
        Configure.With()
            .StructureMapBuilder((IContainer) container)
            .Log4Net()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .UnicastBus()
            .LoadMessageHandlers()
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
    }
}
```

Then in my test, I ensured that my IOC container would use this one instead of the usual web-based one by adding this to my test:

```
IoC.Register<IRunAtStartup, NonWebRunAtStartup>();
```

This got me to a different error, which I'm still fighting with, which I'll ask as a separate question (now NSB can't load assemblies that are in NServiceBus.Core.dll, such as Antlr3.Runtime.dll).

Comment: This is the same solution I ultimately decided against; since I'm trying to test the actual startup it doesn't make much sense to create a separate startup method where the test was the only place it would be called.

Comment: Yeah, I agree the duplication is not ideal.  Unfortunately, it's the best I could come up with (and it works, as long as the two startup classes stay in sync, but that is a manual process)